# what's wrong with my one-liner strncpy: while(*s++ = *t++ && n-- > 0);?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR_BUF    10000
#define STR_MATCH  7

void mystrncpy(char* s, char* t, int n) {
    while(*s++ = *t++ && n-- > 0);
}

int main() {
    int result;
    char str_s[STR_BUF] =  "not so long test string";
    char buf_1[STR_BUF];
    mystrncpy(buf_1, str_s, STR_MATCH);
    printf ("buf_1 (mystrncpy, 7 chars): %s\n", buf_1);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, nothing happened

```
ian@ubuntu:~/tmp$ gcc myncpy.c -o myn&&./myn
buf_1 (mystrncpy, 7chars):
```

Comment: Apart from any bugs, it stops when it sees a null character in the source string. `strncpy` pads the target with zero or more null characters. See also [my rant on the topic](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: "*what's wrong with my one-liner...?*" It's difficult to read an therefore error prone in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assignment has lower precedence than `&&`, so your `while` condition is equivalent to:

```
while (*s++ = (*t++ && n-- > 0))
```

That compares `*s++` to `1` or `0`.  That is not what you want.

```
while ((*s++ = *t++) && n-- > 0)
```

should fix it.

Note that you are still invoking undefined behavior by using `%s` for printing the string.  It hasn't been null-terminated.

```
char buf_1[STR_BUF] = "";
```

is one way to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Logical and( && ) takes greater precedence that equals( = ) so your while expression is actually:

```
while(*s++ = ( *t++ && n-- > 0 ) );
```

Change it to:

```
while( ( *s++ = *t++ ) != '\0' && n-- > 0);
```

to correctly deal with the problem and the null terminator